# Equation 10.2 from The Elements of Statistical Learning. Median of a chi-squared distribution

Tags: classification, boosting, median, chi-squared-distribution, adaboost

I'm reading about AdaBoost in the *The Elements of Statistical Learning* and I don't understand the equation 10.2. Below is an excerpt from the book.

> The power of AdaBoost to dramatically increase the performance of even a very weak classifier is illustrated in Figure 10.2. The features
> $X_1 ,...,X_{10}$ are standard independent Gaussian, and the deterministic target $Y$ is defined by
>
> $ 
> Y= 
> \begin{cases} 
> 1 & \text{if}\,\sum_{j=1}^{10}X_j^2>\chi_{10}^2(0.5), &&&&& (10.2) \\
> -1 & \text{otherwise}. 
> \end{cases}
> $
>
> Here $\chi_{10}^2(0.5)=9.34$ is the median of a chi-squared random
> variable with 10 degrees of freedom (sum of squares of 10 standard
> Gaussians). There are 2000 training cases, with approximately 1000
> cases in each class, and 10,000 test observations. Here the weak classifier is just a “stump”: a two terminal-node classification tree. Applying this classifier alone to the training dataset yields a very poor test set error rate of 45.8%, compared to 50% for random guessing. However, as boosting iterations proceed the error rate steadily decreases, reaching 5.8% after 400 iterations

So, our threshold ($\chi_{10}^2(0.5)$) divides the dataset into 2 classes of equal size. I have 2 questions with that:

1. Why do we want to have classes of equal size?
2. Why is $\chi_{10}^2(0.5)$ the median of a chi-squared distribution with df=10? What does 0.5 stand for?

Comment: "0.5" stands for the median--the 50th percentile.

Comment: $\chi_{10}^2(0.5)$ is potentially ambiguous notation, and you could imagine different authors using it to mean (a) the density of a $\chi^2_{10}$ random variable at $0.5$, in R `dchisq(0.5,10)`; (b) the cumulative probability of a $\chi^2_{10}$ random variable at $0.5$, in R `pchisq(0.5,10)`; (c) the upper cumulative probability of a $\chi^2_{10}$ random variable at $0.5$, in R `pchisq(0.5,10,lower.tail=FALSE)`; (d) the inverse cumulative probability of a $\chi^2_{10}$ random variable at $0.5$, in R `qchisq(0.5,10)`.  Here from the context it means (d)

Comment: To be precise (a) is likelihood that a variable takes value of 0.5. Density at the single point is 0.

Comment: The density is not zero (just type `dchisq(0.5,10)` as suggested by @Henry), the probability is.